# Type-erasure and lambdas: (Partial) template speciallization matching lambda expressions

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, type-erasure

### First of all, some context

As part of a policy-based particle engine I'm currently writting, I have done some type-erasure on policy classes. Specifically, I have done type erasure on the particle evoution policies:

A particle evolution policy is just a policy which says how the data (Coordinates, speed, color, etc) of a particle changes along the simulation. This is its interface:

```
struct evolution_policy
{
    template<PARTICLE_DATA>
    void operator()( PARTICLE_DATA& data );

    void step(); 
};
```

The `operator()` overload just takes a particle data and modifies it acording to the supposed policy. The `step()` function is just a function to update (Advance) the state of the policy (If the policy has some state).

Among other cases, I just needed type erasure to allow the user to use simple function entities (Functions, lambdas, etc) to be used as a evolution policy, for example:

```
add_policy( []( some_particle_data_type& data ) { /* do something with */ } );
```

Where the `add_policy()` function takes some policy and stores it in a vector.  As you can see, the point of type erasure is to treat different kinds of policy classes/entities in the same homogeneous way.

### The problem:

I'm using the dynamic dispatch approach for type erasure:

```
template<tyoename PARTICLE_DATA>
struct type_erased_policy
{
public:
    void operator()( PARTICLE_DATA& data )
    {
        (*_policy)( data );
    }

    void step()
    {
        _policy->step();
    }

private:
    struct policy_interface
    {
        virtual ~policy_interface() {}

        virtual void operator()( PARTICLE_DATA& data ) = 0;
        virtual void step() = 0;
    };

    template<typename POLICY>
    class policy_impl : public policy_interface
    {
    public:
        void operator()( PARTICLE_DATA& data ) override
        {
            _policy( particle );
        }

        void step() override
        {
            _policy.step();
        }

    private:
        POLICY _policy;
    };

    std::shared_ptr<policy_interface> _policy;
};
```

With that in mind, its easy to write an specialization to type-erase shared pointers of policies, for example:

```
template<typename T>
class policy_impl<std::shared_ptr<T>> : public policy_interface
{
public:
    void operator()( PARTICLE_DATA& data ) override
    {
        (*_policy)( data );
    }

    void step( cpp::evolution_policy_step step_type ) override
    {
        _policy->step( step_type );
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> _policy;
};
```

That could be useful if we need to share a policy between particles, for example.

We could write an specialization for `std::function<void(PARTICLE_DATA&)>` policies using that pattern. However, this only works for **explicit instantations of `std::function<void(PARTICLE_DATA&)>`**, i.e. if we pass a lambda function to the `type_erased_policy` ctor, it will instantiate the generic `policy_impl` case, because **there is no specialization for the lambda type.**

As lambda functors (closures) are unique (In other words, the type of a lambda expression is unique and unespecified) **there is no easy way to do this kind of type erasure over a lambda**.

My question is: My goal is to take any function entity (A lambda, a functor, a function pointer, a `std::function`) and do type erasure on it in the way explained above. **Is there any (other) way to match lambdas and/or other function entities to do type-erasure on them?**

### Platform:

I'm using GCC 4.8.2

Comment: @dyp The type-erasure is needed for function entities (Lambdas included) because **they not have a `step()` member function.** If that kind of entities match the primary template, it doesn't compile (Which makes sense).

Comment: Ah, silly me. I overlooked that member function. Well can't you use SFINAE there?

Comment: @dyp I have tried type introspection using type traits (Specifically, `std::is_function`), but an specialization for `std::reference_wrapper` (Similar to the `std::shared_ptr` example I have written in the question) matches it, so it doesn't work for me.

Comment: No, I mean, why don't you check if `_policy.step()` is a valid expression? (You can do this "from inside" the virtual function overrider, by calling some private, SFINAE-overloaded member function.)

Comment: @dyp well, that seems to work. I will try it tomorrow. Thanks. **I really miss concept checking** :(

Comment: http://ideone.com/A6VRlT `std::enable_if` in combination with `has_step`?

Comment: [SFINAE, light version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92e91899d01d1cf4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a policy class that detects `.step()`:

```
namespace impl{
  // eat a type and do nothing with it:
  template<typename T> struct type_sink { typedef void type; };
  template<typename T> using TypeSink = typename type_sink<T>::type;

  // detect .step on T (T& means rvalue, T means lvalue, and T const& means const lvalue, etc)
  template<typename T, typename=void>
  struct has_step:std::false_type {};

  template<typename T>
  struct has_step<T, TypeSink< decltype( std::declval<T>().step() ) > >:
    std::true_type
  {};
}
template<typename T> struct has_step : impl::has_step<T> {};
```

So now we have a `has_step<T>` traits class that is `true_type` if `T` has a `.step()` method callable, and `false_type` otherwise.

If we are feeding this to a function, we can pick which implementation to run with tag dispatching:

```
template<typename T>
return_type_whatever type_erase_helper( T&& t, std::true_type /* test passed */ ) {
  // branch 1
}
template<typename T>
return_type_whatever type_erase_helper( T&& t, std::false_type /* test failed */ ) {
  // branch 2
}
template<typename T>
return_type_whatever type_erase( T&& t ) {
  return type_erase_helper( std::forward<T>(t), has_step< typename std::decay<T>::type& >() );
}
```

If you really want to specialize a particular class based on having `step` or not, you can use SFINAE techniques.  But type erasure does not rely on the type erasure implementation being based off of specialization: I'd just use tag dispatching on the function that generates the type erasure implementation object.

We can daisy-chain such tag dispatching.  Another good one might be `is_signature_compatible< T, R(Args...) >`:

```
namespace impl {
  template<typename T, typename Sig,typename=void>
  struct is_signature_compatible:std::false_type {};
  template<typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
  struct is_signature_compatible< T, R(Args...), typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_convertible< typename std::result_of< T(Args...) >::type, R >::value
  >::type >:std::true_type {};
  // dunno if this is needed?  Possibly, and shouldn't hurt:
  template<typename T, typename... Args>
  struct is_signature_compatible< T, void(Args...),
    TypeSink< typename std::result_of< T(Args...) >::type >
  >:std::true_type {};
}
template<typename T, typename Sig>
struct is_signature_compatible:impl::is_signature_compatible<T,Sig> {};
```

which we can then use to split the wheat from the chaff in a less "error occurs 10 recursive `template` invocations deep" way.

Comment: C++ without "error occurs 10 recursive template invocations deep" loses most of its appeal, don't you think?

Comment: `TypeSink< decltype( std::declval<T>().step() ) >` Why not `decltype( std::declval<T>().step(), void() )`?

Comment: @dyp You never know when someone will figure out how to overload `foo,void`?  (I kid).  I just like making my `sink`s explicit.  Also see second use of `TypeSink` where there is no expression: introducing `,` there would be wordy.

Comment: Almost guessed that.. But it seems a bit complicated to me: You could use `template<class T> using TypeSink = void;` or if you want to keep a special tag type, `struct type_sink{}; template<class T> using TypeSink = type_sink;` and specialize for `type_sink` instead of `void`.

Comment: @dyp true: I based it off of pre-C++11 type sinking, and then off `identity`.  I do like `void`, as it is also the default output of `enable_if`.  Really, `type_sink<x,y=void>` would probably be best: let you sink any type to any output type.  For identity I think that level of indirection blocks type deduction?  Dunno if anything similar happens here with the indirection, probably not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm agree with @dyp, that implementation details seems to me a bit overcomplicated. While reading the answer, I was guessing about *"why not `using TYpeSink = void`"* and *tag dispatching instead of `void`*. I was glad to see thats exactly what dyp has noted and you have discussed that details in deep in the comments. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One question, just to be sure: The point of this implemenation is that when the type has not a `step()` member function the speciallization is ill-formed (SFINAE kicks in) and thus the primary template is instantiated, right? (Sorry, I'm talking about the `has_step` helper)

Comment: @manu343726 yes, when it lacks `.step()`, substitution failure occurs, so the `: std::true_type` specialization fails, and the remaining one is the base `: std::false_type`.  By isolatimg that check in a trait like this, we both make code elsewhere simpler, and allow tag dispatching based on `.step()` existing.  Tag dispatching in turn lets us create the lambda and `.step()` type erasure internal pImpl differently.

Answer (score 3):

To facilitate [the technique](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil) wrap your lambda function in a `std::function`. Since its constructor is greedy, it will absorbe any callable, yet the gain of wrapping would be declaring an **explicit type**

```
auto f1 = [](double a, double b)->int {
    return a + b > 5.; // example function body
});

std::function<int(double,double)> f2 ( [](double a, double b)->int {
    return a + b > 5.; // example function body
};);
```

So in the above context `f1` faces the problems you mention, while `f2` **is a lambda** (preserves all the convinience in declaring and using it) that, in a sense, has no 'stray type'

Comment: That's exactly what I'm currently doing, but what I want is to avoid that, and just write a lambda